# PostgreSQL tsearch2 without lowercasing

Tags: postgresql, case-sensitive

I use the tsearch2 in PostgreSQL to extract the urls from text. Everything works fine with default tools, but there's a problem with YouTube links: urls which I get from parser are all lowercased - and YT links cannot be.

I did a little research and found that there is no option that could disable lowering - all I could do is to write my own parser.

Am I right? Maybe there is any magic way to make parser case-sensitive? If no - is there anybody with appropriate parser written? If also no - do you have any advices, how to do it properly? :)

Thanks for help,
xaru

Answer (score 1):

you can recheck tsearch result by LIKE that is case sensitive. If there are not too much conflicts, then this solution should be fast

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT url
                  FROM your_tab
                 WHERE to_tsvector(..) @@ to_tsquery(..)
                 OFFSET 0) s
  WHERE s.url LIKE '%Bbx%'
```

Comment: I'm afraid it will not work. I use following code to extract urls:


`SELECT id,to_tsvector('public.urls_extraction', content) AS url
 FROM pages...`



I store this tsvectors in separate table, from where I get them when I need to query something.

If I use your code, I get this error:
`ERROR: operator does not exist: tsvector ~~* unknown`

Comment: you cannot use LIKE to tsvector type, but to original string